# Add multiple UIView’s indie a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

[image]

I need to create a view which has 3 labels, left centre and right. And place this view programmatically inside a UIView that’s inside my StoryBoard. The labels would be reused each time this view is added.

I’m using storyboard for my app design but need to do this programmatically as I may have to use this view between 1 to 10 times, stacked vertically on each page and have 10 pages. So to create 100 views with 300 levels and work with hiding/showing them would take forever.

What’s the best approach for this? I thought of using tableView but had problems trying to create a smal table with just 1 to 10 cells without scrolling and contain it within that view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a stack view can fill your needs to manage labels. Create a type StackWithLabels with @IBDesignable to be able to add the stack view programmatically or from Storyboard.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let stackWithLabels = StackWithLabels(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size))
        stackWithLabels.distribution = .fillEqually

        view.addSubview(stackWithLabels)
    }
}

@IBDesignable
class StackWithLabels: UIStackView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let label1 = UILabel(); label1.text = "Label 1"
        let label2 = UILabel(); label2.text = "Label 2"
        let label3 = UILabel(); label3.text = "Label 3"

        addArrangedSubview(label1)
        addArrangedSubview(label2)
        addArrangedSubview(label3)
        arrangedSubviews.forEach { ($0 as? UILabel)?.textAlignment = .center }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Can you show me how to add 2 of those programmatically in the stackview with different labels? So the first one will have Label1 Label2 Label3 and the second one Test1 Test2 Test3?